# Oulook email client : CSS properties not supported

Tags: html, css, outlook, email-templates

I want to wrap long string within block but it looks like `overflow: hidden` and `word-wrap: break-word` CSS properties are not supported in **Outlook**. Is anyone have any idea how to use those or any other equivalent solution.

Comment: using `overflow:hidden` would only hide the content right? it is not wrapping a long string within a block, is it? I would expect that if the content is to large for the width of your block you make the height dynamic. But I guess that would be no solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an 'official' list of all the tags Outlook ignores, but this one seems fairly definitive: https://www.outlook-apps.com/html-ignored-by-outlook/

Have you tried this variation? It seems to work in Outlook 2013 so should work in everything above 2003 hopefully.

`<p style="word-break:break-all;">
   superlongstringwouldgohereandhopefullybreakwhenthecontainingptagrunsout
</p>`